# I can't get my javascript to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bower

This is head section of my code bringing my Javascript and CSS libraries, but it won't run my jQuery file

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "bower_componets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "darkly.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "HistorySytleSheet.css"/>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "bower_component/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "bower_component/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src = "HistoryJQ.js"></script>
```

fir those that are asking this is the Jquery I'm trying to run

```
var main = function () {
    $('arrow-next').click(function () {
        var currentSlide = $('active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        var currentDot = $('active-dot');
        var nextDot = currentDot.next();

        if(nextSlide.length === 0)
        {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
            nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        }   

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        nextDot.addClass('active-dot'); 
    });


        $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
      prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
      prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
  });

};

$(document).readyState(main);
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are you sure the path to files are correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use a descriptive title. It would also be helpful to include any error messages.

Comment: two of your link elements arent properly closed

Comment: @PatrickEvans this is specifically tagged HTML5 in which they are all closed properly, but confusingly in two different ways

Comment: how did you know jquery is not working ? did you check with fixing breakpoints inside jquery  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess:

You have:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "bower_componets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Then you have:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "bower_component/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "bower_component/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm *guessing* you mistyped `bower_componets` and `bower_component`, which both should probably be: `bower_components`.
That means you're probably not loading jquery and bootstrap.

Give this a try:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```